# Access safety of getters in Java

Tags: java, getter-setter, access-modifiers

So, we created a simple class with some private class member and automatically generated getter for it. But getter actually returned a reference to that member, resulting in gaining full access to a private member. Is that okay?
Here's the code of a class:

```
public class User {

    private ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList(){ {
            add("String1");
            add("String2");
        } };

    public User() {
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getStrings() {
        return strings;
    }

    public void setStrings(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }
}
```

Code of main method:

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        User user = new User();

        System.out.println(user.getStrings());
        user.getStrings().add("String3");
        System.out.println(user.getStrings());
    }
}
```

And output:

[String1, String2]

[String1, String2, String3]

I've changed the getter to this one:

```
public ArrayList<String> getStrings() {
    return (ArrayList<String>)strings.clone();
}
```

But the question remains, what getters are for if not for safety? And what is the right way to write them?

Comment: There is nothing wrong

Comment: No, this is not okay in most circumstances. You will probably want to expose methods that _act_ on the `List` rather than the `List` itself. You also don't want to directly consume a `List` from the setter.

Comment: It is okay if you plan to add elements to your list in your main function as you are doing. If you clone, the changes are not memorized until you call the setter.

Comment: As i see you are kind-of using immutability. I would suggest you to read a bit on the topic of creatin soft or strong immutable objects.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140528113353-16837833-6-benefits-of-programming-with-immutable-objects-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't okay because it breaks encapsulation and thus the class can't maintain its own invariants. Same with constructors.

But the problem isn't with getters/setters, it's with the code that autogenerates them.

To cut a long story short: don't use autogenerated accessors blindly, if they're dealing with mutable structures, make defensive copies (or immutable equivalents).

---

As an aside, I would not have a getter with an `ArrayList` return type, even if it's just a copy. It's usually none of the client's business what kind of list you're returning, so my getter would look like this:

```
public List<String> getStrings() {
    return new ArrayList<>(strings);
}
```

Or using an immutable view:

```
public List<String> getStrings() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(strings);
}
```

Or using Guava's `ImmutableList` class:

```
public List<String> getStrings() {
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(strings);
}
```

There are subtle differences between the three solutions so which one's best may vary. As a general rule I prefer returning immutable structures because that makes it clear that changes made to the structure won't be reflected, i.e. `user.getStrings().add( "X" );` will fail with an exception.

---

Another subtle problem with the code you showed us is the double braces initialisation. Imagine a class like this:

```
public class Foo {
   private List<String> strings = new ArrayList() {{ add("bar");}};
   private Object veryLargeField; //the object stored here consumes a lot of memory

   public List<String> getStrings() {
     return strings;
   }
}
```

Now imagine we're doing this:

```
private class Bar {
   private List<String> fooStrings;

   public Bar() {
     this.fooStrings = new Foo().getStrings();
   }
}
```

How much memory would `Bar` consume (or to use the precise term: retain)? Well, it turns out that quite a lot, because what you do with the double brace initialisation is create an anonymous inner class, which will contain a reference to its outer class (`Foo`), and thus while the list returned is accessible, all the other fields of `Foo` will be ineligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Copying is very expensive. It's almost always best to return an immutable _view_ and then the consumer can copy it if needs be.

Comment: @BoristheSpider How expensive it is depends on a lot of factors. Returning an immutable view works for getters but setters and constructors **must** make a copy. In getters it's up to you whether you make a copy or a view. The important lesson is that you shouldn't stop doing the right thing just because you think it is going to be expensive.

Comment: Well, a copy must be at least `O(n)` and creating a view (at least with the JDK classes) is `O(1)`. Agreed on constructors, that's why I said _return_ not _consume_. My argument is that you should **always** _return_ an immutable view and the _consumer_ decides whether to copy it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider What if your list is small anyway? What if your getter is only invoked a few times? What if a JIT compiler optimizes the copying away completely? If you want to argue in favour of immutable views, a better argument would be that even a stupid client will know it's just a view because modification attempts will fail with an exception rather than just silently.

Comment: I don't quite understand how to create immutable view of a class, could you please explain that?

Comment: P.S. +1 - this answer certainly covers important points and the note on double-brace injt is certainly warranted. I don't know where that trend started but it's horrendous.

Comment: @biziclop size makes no difference because either way you need to create a `List` object - in the copy case you need to copy the contents aswell; always slower. The JIT cannot optimise copying away unless it's dead code - this would then also apply in the view case - this is a nonsense argument. As far as how many times the getter is called, if a view is always faster, see above, then this is also moot.

Comment: @user2979453 take a look at [`java.util.Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-).

Comment: I think it is quite dangerous to get to religious here. What is right or wrong depends a lot on the actual interface definition of the class. While I agree in general with most of the statements, I cannot agree with the strong this is the right way to do it statement. Just think as an example of the decorator pattern. In most cases it would be plain wrong to create a copy when feeding in the list to be decorated.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't know why we're arguing because I agree that returning immutable structures is better in general. The reason I don't like the speed argument is mainly that it glosses over the fact that returning a copy and returning a view are not functionally equivalent, which I think is far more important.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view getters usually should serve two purposes:

- first they should guard the implementation details.
- second they should provide a way to extend easily (e.g.  validation or instrumentation)

If your example violates these principles depends on the context:

1. If your class should own the strings then probably everyone should interact with the container object to modify the list and not with the list itself. To expose a collection (e.g.  For processing in a method that expects a collection) you can use e.g. Collections.unmodifiableList(). If on the other hand the class only owns the list of strings then it is not an implementation detail to have a list.
2. Using a getter instead of directly accessing the fields allows you to easily add data conversation, tracing instrumentation and other things without changing all the places where the field is used.